# Joomla: How do I make a login page just like Joomla's backend?

Tags: authentication, joomla, joomla3.0

I want my homepage to be like Joomla's administration page, meaning there is only a login form displayed on the page. The hard part is, although it is not hard to make a homepage like this and I can set redirection after login to another page, if a logged in user close their browser tab and reopen the homepage, they will just see the login form which now only displays a logout button. I can put a link here for them to get to the other pages, but that is awkward and not a very good behavior. I want it to be just like Joomla's administration page, meaning if you are logged in, when you close and reopen browser tab, you will directly get to the administration panel skipping the login page. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try making your homepage accessible to registered(not public) user only? This way they will be redirected to the login page if not logged in or will see homepage if logged in.

Comment: I've tried this approach, strangely, on most of sites, if I set the homepage to "registered", I'll get an error saying "redirect too many times"